# SetInterval() is applied thrice or twice automatically based on the number of times I click on button

Tags: javascript

```
    firsttime = time1;
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
      firsttime++;
    }, 1000);
```

Here previous Interval remains and gets added even if I click the button and goes to next button and come back again

Comment: please add the button part/s as well.

Comment: <strong><span id="timer1" style="margin-left:12px;"></span></strong>
        &nbsp<strong><span id="timer2" style="margin-left:25px"></span></strong>
        &nbsp<strong><span id="timer3" style="margin-left:29px"></span></strong>

Answer (score 1):

Unless you clear it with `clearInterval(downloadTimer)`, obviously if the page is not reloaded multiple intervals will be created when calling `setInterval` multiple times.

Comment: The problem is happening that after applying clearInterval the timer ccompletely stops at the last time and does not count further. var downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
      fivetime++;
      document.getElementById("timer5").textContent = fivetime; 
                 clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    }, 1000);

Comment: Yes, clearInterval stops the timer. What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: What I want to achieve is to start the timer again from same value once clearInterval stops it

Comment: If you don't reset firsttime then it will continue from there.